# Initiating Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there any way to run the android emulator without opening Android Studio or any code editor?
I tried it by pinning the application but it did not work.

I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -avd <avd-name>
```

assuming `<avd-name>` is the name of a previously created AVD.

See more command line options [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#common).

Answer (score 0):

We can use emulator using command line tools to start emulator without android studio. [Documentation link here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline)

```
<SDKLocation>\emulator\emulator.exe -avd <avd-name>
```

You can include different parameters along with avd name.